# Factory Method return Spring service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, factory-pattern, factory-method

I want a factory class that return a service that I can use to do some validations. I implemented this class

```
public class EventUpdateValidatorFactory {

    public EventUpdateValidatorStrategy getValidator(EEventStatus eventStatus) {

        if (SECOND_APPROVAL.equals(eventStatus)) {
            return new EventSecondApprovalValidator();
        } else if (APPROVED.equals(eventStatus)) {
            return new EventApprovedValidator();
        } else if (ACCOUNTING_HQ.equals(eventStatus)) {
            return new EventAccountingHqValidator();
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown status");
    }
}
```

The interface **EventUpdateValidatorStrategy** is this

```
public interface EventUpdateValidatorStrategy {

    default <T extends EventUpdateValidatorStrategy> void validate(User user, EventMasterData masterData, Event event, List<EventExternalSystemExpenseSave> expenses,
            List<EventExternalSystemSpeakerSave> speakers, long eventId) {

        this.validateMasterData(masterData, event);
        this.validateSpeakers(speakers, eventId);
        this.validateExpenses(expenses, eventId);
        this.doUpdate(user, masterData, expenses, speakers, eventId);

    }

    void validateMasterData(EventMasterData masterData, Event event);
    void validateExpenses(List<EventExternalSystemExpenseSave> expenses, long eventId);
    void validateSpeakers(List<EventExternalSystemSpeakerSave> speakers, long eventId);
    void doUpdate(User user, EventMasterData masterData, List<EventExternalSystemExpenseSave> expenses, List<EventExternalSystemSpeakerSave> speakers, long eventId);

}
```

The **EventSecondApprovalValidator** is this

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EventSecondApprovalValidator implements EventUpdateValidatorStrategy {

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @Autowired
    private ContextDateService contextDateService;

    @Autowired
    private EventExpenseService eventExpenseService;

    @Autowired
    private EventExternalSystemDAO eventExternalSystemDAO;

    @Override
    public void validateMasterData(LocalEventMasterData masterData, Event event) {
        // some logic
    }

    @Override
    public void validateExpenses(List<EventExternalSystemExpenseSave> expenses, long eventId) {
        // some logic
    }

    @Override
    public void validateSpeakers(List<EventExternalSystemSpeakerSave> speakers, long eventId) {
        // some logic
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdate(User user, EventMasterData masterData, List<EventExternalSystemExpenseSave> expenses, List<EventExternalSystemSpeakerSave> speakers, long eventId) {
        ofNullable(expenses).ifPresent(expensesToSave -> expensesToSave.forEach(expense -> this.eventExternalSystemDAO.updateExpense(user, expense)));
        this.eventExternalSystemDAO.updateEvent(user, masterData, eventId);
    }

}
```

The other **EventApprovedValidator** and **EventAccountingHqValidator** implementations are similar.

From main code I do this call

```
final EventUpdateValidatorStrategy validator = EventUpdateValidatorFactory.getValidator(event.getStatus());
        validator.validate(user, eventSave.getMasterData(), event, eventSave.getExpenses(), eventSave.getSpeakers(), eventID);
```

and the result is that when I enter inside a **EventSecondApprovalValidator** all the autowired services are null and, obviously, I receive a NPE the first time that I use one of that service.

How I correctly use the factory to return the service that I need based on **EEventStatus**?

Comment: You don't have to create a factory manually, coz spring already has a spring bean factory for doing this. Simple rule is if you are autowiring `@Autowired Myclass obj` then some where you should expose `@Component Myclass{}` or create a `@Bean method in @Configuration class` that provides obj of type Myclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `EventUpdateValidatorFactory.getValidator(EEventStatus)` method, you need to return the `EventSecondApprovalValidator` bean from context, instead of creating a new instance using `new` keyword.

The class `EventSecondApprovalValidator` is `@Service` annotated (and assuming there is only one of this type), an instance of this type will be added to `ApplicationContext` by Spring with all dependencies injected. So, just fetch it from context and use it.

One quick way to do this is as follows:

```
public EventUpdateValidatorStrategy getValidator(ApplicationContext context, 
        EEventStatus eventStatus) {

    if (SECOND_APPROVAL.equals(eventStatus)) {
        return context.getBean(EventSecondApprovalValidator.class);
    } else if (APPROVED.equals(eventStatus)) {
        return context.getBean(EventApprovedValidator.class);
    } else if (ACCOUNTING_HQ.equals(eventStatus)) {
        return context.getBean(EventAccountingHqValidator.class);
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown status");
}
```

You can also `@Autowire` all validators in `EventUpdateValidatorFactory` and return the `@Autowired` instances. This will keep the `getValidator` method's signature same, but you'll have to make `EventUpdateValidatorFactory` a `@Component`-esque class.

```
@Component
public class EventUpdateValidatorFactory {

    @Autowired
    EventSecondApprovalValidator a;

    @Autowired
    EventApprovedValidator b;

    @Autowired
    EventAccountingHqValidator c;

    public EventUpdateValidatorStrategy getValidator(EEventStatus eventStatus) {

        if (SECOND_APPROVAL.equals(eventStatus)) {
            return a;
        } else if (APPROVED.equals(eventStatus)) {
            return b;
        } else if (ACCOUNTING_HQ.equals(eventStatus)) {
            return c;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown status");
    }
```

Comment: I like your second solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: yes, both solution they works! But I think that your second solution is more elegant. What do you think about it?

Comment: Most consider use of `Application.getBean` to be an anti-pattern/misuse/abuse. So, yes, makes sense to use second one. Both should work just fine though.

Answer (score -2):

Creating an object manually you are not letting Spring perform autowiring. Consider managing your services by Spring as well.

```
 @Component
public class MyServiceAdapter implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceOne myServiceOne;

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceTwo myServiceTwo;

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceThree myServiceThree;

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceDefault myServiceDefault;

    public boolean checkStatus(String service) {
        service = service.toLowerCase();

        if (service.equals("one")) {
            return myServiceOne.checkStatus();
        } else if (service.equals("two")) {
            return myServiceTwo.checkStatus();
        } else if (service.equals("three")) {
            return myServiceThree.checkStatus();
        } else {
            return myServiceDefault.checkStatus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your example